# Did not get JSON parse result on fragment android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I want to get `JSON` to fill edittext, on fragment java I wrote like this :

```
public class banktransferfragment extends Fragment {
Intent intent;
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ArrayList<String> banktransferlist;
ArrayList<BankTransferModel> banktransfer;
EditText editText_BankAccountName, editText_BankAccountNumber, editText_BankName, editText_csemail, editText_csphone;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "BankTransfer";
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bank_transfer, container, false);
    banktransfer = new ArrayList<BankTransferModel>();
    banktransferlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    final String token= extras.getString("TOKEN");
    final String checkbox_state= extras.getString("checkbox_state");
    editText_BankAccountName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_BankAccountName);
    editText_BankAccountNumber = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_BankAccountNumber);
    editText_BankName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_BankName);
    editText_csemail = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_csemail);
    editText_csphone = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_csphone);
    // JSON file URL address
    SendfeedbackJob job = new SendfeedbackJob();
    job.execute();
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LegalNoticePage.class);
    intent.putExtra("checkbox_state", checkbox_state);
    intent.putExtra("TOKEN", token);
    final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.transaction_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
private class SendfeedbackJob extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "BankTransfer";
    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    final String token= extras.getString("TOKEN");
    final String checkbox_state= extras.getString("checkbox_state");
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        final String url_bank_transfer = Constant.URI_BASE_CONFIG + "?token=" + token;
        Utils.log("url_bank_transfer: " + url_bank_transfer);
        try{
            // Locate the NodeList name
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url_bank_transfer);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Utils.log("data transfer: " + data);
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = json.getJSONObject(i);
                final String BankAccountName=jsonobject.getString("bank_account_name");
                final String BankAccountNumber=jsonobject.getString("bank_account_number");
                final String BankName=jsonobject.getString("bank_name");
                final String csemail=jsonobject.getString("cs_email");
                final String csphone=jsonobject.getString("cs_phone");
                Utils.log("BankAccountName: " + BankAccountName);

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        editText_BankAccountName.setText(BankAccountName);
                        editText_BankAccountNumber.setText(BankAccountNumber);
                        editText_BankName.setText(BankName);
                        editText_csemail.setText(csemail);
                        editText_csphone.setText(csphone);
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, String.format("Error during bank transfer: %s", e.getMessage()));
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "processing";
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        //process onPostExecute
    }
}
}
```

**Update**:
I got `Utils.log("url_bank_transfer: " + url_bank_transfer); and Utils.log("data transfer: " + data);`

```
[{"site_tittle":"Book My Fit","global_class_fee":"50000","bank_account_name":"Book My Fit","bank_account_number":"xxxxxxxxxx","bank_name":"BCA Cabang Permata Hijau","cs_email":"cs@bookmyfit.com","cs_phone":"+62215135143","sandbox_vt_client_key":"VT-client-OnqFmrAF1lmDR_aI","sandbox_vt_server_key":"VT-server-0T91A-yygrsiaJdZtq591H7s","production_vt_client_key":"not-available","production_vt_server_key":"not-available","footer_1":"about","footer_2":"learn more","footer_3":"partners","footer_4":"connect","site_description_en":"BookMyFit.com is your new fitness partner that allows you a monthly membership to hundreds of gyms, fitness studios and activities in your city, so you can try something new every day. Download the mobile app & get ready for your fitness journey.","site_description_id":"BookMyFit.com adalah partner fitness terbaru yang memungkinkan anda mendapatkan membership bulanan ke ratusan gym, studio fitness dan aktivitas dikota anda, sehingga anda bisa mencoba sesuatu yang baru setiap harinya. Download aplikasi untuk mobile dan be","office_address":"370, Palma One Building<br \/> Jl. H.R. Rasuna Said Kav. X-2\/4<br \/> Jakarta 12950 - Indonesia<br \/> +62 21 5228775"}]
```

How to correct that to make text appear on edittext?

**Update:** it seems change in `JSON` become `JSONArray` to make it work. Question closed.

Comment: Debug and check if you are getting response from `url` or not?

Comment: Also check you added internet permission and Stop using HttpClient its deprecated try UrlConnection.

Comment: I got this log Utils.log("url_bank_transfer: " + url_bank_transfer);

Comment: Please post your json format

Comment: hi please just check you are getting value in Method onPostExecute() or not .

Comment: You are getting a Jsonobject as you posted in Question ? or an array which you improvise to get the above object ?. Make use of the debug option and check the flow of program is as you expected.

Comment: stack trace is type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray. it seems need [ and ] before { and after }

Comment: Are you sure that your first tag is `JSONArray`? Log displays that it is `JSONObject`.

Comment: that is why I want to change to JSONArray use [ and ] , because when I log Utils.log("BankAccountName: " + BankAccountName); it did not show. I thought because it use JSONObject.

Comment: Also your code is totally wrong. You can't call `onPostExecute()` in `doInBackGround` method because it is `override` method of `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @TanyaKode So finally did u solve ur problem?

Comment: solved. I update the correct code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93649/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-tanya-kode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You getting your `data` as an whole `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`. So you have to put `data` in `JSONObject`. Try like this.

```
                JSONObject jsonobject= new JSONObject(data);        
                String BankAccountName=jsonobject.getString("bank_account_name");
                String BankAccountNumber=jsonobject.getString("bank_account_number");
                String BankName=jsonobject.getString("bank_name");
                String csemail=jsonobject.getString("cs_email");
                String csphone=jsonobject.getString("cs_phone");
```